# Switch Error Codes

Tags: android

How do I create an error handler in Android. In .Net I would simply create a handler the switch the error codes to relay the correct response required to the user.

In this case I am using a SAX parser surrounded by try and catch, when an error is raised I obviously get a message but no unique error ID. there may be ten errors captured by the try\catch block but how do I distinguish between the errors so I can try and handle the expected errors?

Ideally something like this:

```
switch (e.getErrorID){
case 1000:
   //Handle This Expected Error
break;
case 1064:
    //Handle This Expected Error
break;
case 2025:
    //Handle This Expected Error
break;
default:
    //Unexpexted Error
}
```

Maybe I should mention, the error im trying to catch is empty document

Answer (score 3):

Jay Dee,

In Java its typically frowned upon to have a generic exception handler.  This link provides a good explanation: http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#dont-catch-generic-exception

You'll want to do something more like...

```
try {
        //stuff
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //specific handling for NumberFormatException
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
        //specific handling for NullPointerException 
}
```

Comment: I'm not happy to follow along a frowned path as you can imagine, however I am now investigating the parser.getErrorHandler(new xmlErrorHandler()) but not quite got it as the raised error doesn't seem to be calling the handler... yet?

Answer (score 1):

You could throw specific exceptions (possibly all extending a common base exception) and handle each in its own `catch` block.

You could alternatively implement a single generic exception with a `getErrorCode` method on which you could switch in a single `catch` block. (BTW this is the approach used in [SQLException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getErrorCode%28%29)).

Specific exception approach:

```
throw new MissingAttributeException("a_mandatory_attr");
throw new InvalidAttributeValueException("some_attr", badValue);
```

or generic approach:

```
throw new GenericParsingException(MISSING_ATTRIBUTE, "a_mandatory_attr");
throw new GenericParsingException(INVALID_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE, "some_attr", badValue);
```

You probably find that it may be easier to throw and handle specific exceptions. This makes it easy to construct with and access different content.

Comment: Ahhhhh you may be able to help me further, I understand throwing these exceptions should be handled by a Parser handler, I have now implemented a separate class as a handler but the handler isn't being called and is still falling back on to the try\catch statement. I'm setting my handler as follows >parser.setErrorHandler(new xmlErrorHandler())< xmlErrorHandler being the handler class... buit it doesn't seem to be called???

Comment: (It's been a long while since I wrote a SAX parser.) I think your ErrorHandler is invoked by the parsing library itself, for validation errors and such like. So it gives you chance to handle these if you want to. However, you can still throw SAXParseExceptions from your own code. I think these would emerge at parser.parse().

Answer (score 1):

Can you use multiple catch blocks in your code?

```
try {
// code
}catch(error1 e){
//error1 handling code
}catch(error2 e){
//error2 handling
}
```

and so on.